# subclassing a react native component doesn't work anymore

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm upgrading from expo 37 to expo 42, but stumbled in a problem unrelated to the specific version. The most obvious change is that now the architecture has changed from class based components to functional components. So I'm unable to reuse my code, for instance in the following snippet (you can test with `$ expo init test_touchable` and replacing App.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

// the purpose is to change the activeOpacity property in a systematic way...
class Touchable extends TouchableHighlight {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
}
Touchable.defaultProps = {
  activeOpacity: 0.3
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Touchable onPress={() => alert('cucu')}><Text>qwe qwe</Text></Touchable>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Now I get this error,

```
$ expo start
Starting project at /home/carlo/test/expo/test_touchable
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Starting Metro Bundler
... etc etc... open expo go using the qr code ...
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Android Bundling complete 3465ms
Android Running app on ........

Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:200:6 in runApplication

TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0

...
```

that hints the fact that `TouchableHighlight` is not more a class.
How can I use again the subclass pattern ?